# Error with trigonometric operations using numba

Tags: python, numba

I want to implement a function using numba to accelerate the execution speed of my algorithm. Nonetheless, upon executing my code, I obtain an error which is completely incomprehensible to me, and I struggle to solve. Nonetheless, I pointed out that it is due the use of cos and sin functions.

```
@njit
def Metropolis(lattice, times, BJ, energy):
    spins = np.copy(lattice)
    net_spins = np.zeros(times-1)
    net_energy = np.zeros(times-1)

    for t in range(0,times-1):
        # 2. pick random point on array and flip spin
        x = np.random.randint(0,N)
        y = np.random.randint(0,N)
        spin_i = spins[x,y] #initial spinx
        
        spin_f_temp = np.random.choice(list, 1)
        # compute change in energy
        
        E_i = 0
        E_f = 0
        if x>0:
            E_i = E_i - np.cos(spins[x-1,y]-spin_i)
            E_f = E_f - np.cos(spins[x-1,y]-spin_f_temp)
        if x<N-1:
            E_i = E_i - np.cos(spins[x+1,y]-spin_i)
            E_f = E_f - np.cos(spins[x+1,y]-spin_f_temp)
        if y>0:
            E_i = E_i - np.cos(spins[x,y-1]-spin_i)
            E_f = E_f - np.cos(spins[x,y-1]-spin_f_temp)
        if y<N-1:
            E_i = E_i - np.cos(spins[x,y+1]-spin_i)
            E_f = E_f - np.cos(spins[x,y+1]-spin_f_temp)
                
        dE = E_f-E_i
        if (dE>0)*(np.random.random() < np.exp(-BJ*dE)):
            spins[x,y]=spin_f_temp
            energy += dE
        elif dE<=0:
            spins[x,y]=spin_f_temp
            energy += dE

        net_spins[t] = spins.sum()
        net_energy[t] = energy

    return net_spins, net_energy, spins`
```

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
    Cannot unify Literal[int](0) and array(float64, 1d, C) for 'E_f.5', defined at        C:\Users\demet\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_25716\1172949613.py (22)

    File "AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_25716\1172949613.py", line 22:
    <source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

    During: typing of assignment at C:\Users\demet\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_25716\1172949613.py   (22)

    File "AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_25716\1172949613.py", line 22:
    <source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

list is an externally defined numpy array of elements.

Thank you in advance

What is the reason I get this error. I can't see why.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you are mixing arrays and integers.
Your spins accessed by position from the lattice are integers, but your `spin_f_temp` value is an one dimensional array of length one. so you could fix your code by taking the value from this array.

```
spin_f_temp = np.random.choice(spinlist, 1)[0]
```

Note that I renamed the global variable `list` to `spinlist`, because it is bad practice to chose a language defined name for a variable.

Further note:
If this is not an exercise, but you really want to use this code for your research, I would recommend to use an existing Ising-Model Monte-Carlo Simulation. As a developer you never want to reinvent the wheel and as a scientist you are always happy to cite someone.